# Synonymize [tkinter] with [tk]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) is Python bindings to [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk).

Since:

- a question about it will have to include [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python),
- it will probably also include [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) to cover more audience since anything Tkinter has a direct equivalent in pure Tk,
- hardly anyone will be using Tk from Python in any other way

the [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) tag in the question is redundant and only occupies a limited space in tag slots.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As closer (i.e. source) inspection of Tkinter shows, astonishingly enough (since docs gloss over this fact entirely, Tkinter doesn't even have its own documentation), Tkinter is not just some "Python bindings for Tcl/Tk".

Rather, it's a full-fledged middleware with lots of custom logic that makes Tcl's interface more pythonic -- most prominently, hides its extremely unorthodox threading model and presents something closer to standard programming practice.

As a result, its interface has a large portion that has no counterpart in either Tcl or Tk (even though most widget-related calls map directly into Tcl commands) and thus deserves a separate tag.

Answer (score 12):

No. [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) and [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) are **two separate, distinct entities**.

- [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) is the GUI library, which most often is associated with the TCL language but can be used from any language with C library support.
- [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) is the Python binding for the above. This intergration includes a Python object model that’s quite distinct from the Tk message sending API.

There are plenty of Python Tkinter questions that are only tagged with [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter), and tons of questions tagged with [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) that are not Python related. Because of the Python OO wrapper used in Tkinter, experts in using Tkinter will usually struggle with general Tk questions and Tk experts with a background from other languages will be unfamiliar with the Python model.

Making [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) a synonym would force [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) experts to have to filter out a very large number of irrelevant questions. It is a pity that experts in the [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) tag already have to do the same whenever someone with a Python/Tkinter question adds the [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) tag. Creating a synonym would make matters worse, not better.

Instead, feel free to remove the [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) tag from Python questions with the [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) tag where there is no specific Tk component (so dealing with the internals of the Tkinter wrapper or where the interactions with Tkinter expose the abstraction to such an extend that Tk knowledge is helpful).

For example, the issue in [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982496/listbox-getting-key-events-with-diacritics-instead-of-national-characters) could be either the Tkinter integration or the underlying Tk implementation. Both tags are warranted. But [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126818/how-to-make-code-more-compact) the [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) tag was definitely misplaced, so I removed it.

Comment: My thoughts exactly... I started drafting something a couple of hours ago but had to direct attention elsewhere... but this would have been pretty much the post I'd have ended up with :) (thanks for saving me time completing it :p)

Comment: _"feel free to remove the tk tag from Python questions with the tkinter tag where there is no specific Tk component"_ ...Come again? Every widget is a Tk component. [There's even no separate official documentation for Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: most Python code using `tkinter` is only touching that integration layer, and are asking about how to achieve some simple task with that layer (creating instances of widget classes, setting up a layout, registering callbacks). I'm well aware how the Tkinter documentation is organised.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: the most common problem then is people storing the `.grid()` or `.pack()` method call results rather than the specific widget instance, or how to pass along arguments to callbacks. A Tk expert without the Python background would be able to help there.