# The [tk] tag should not be a synonym of [tkinter]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-removal-request

I just noticed (when retagging a question) that it looks like someone aliased [tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk) and [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) despite this question here:

- [Synonymize [tkinter] with [tk]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363835/synonymize-tkinter-with-tk)

*specifically* indicating that this should *not* be done. They're separate substantial pieces of software (Tkinter is built in part on top of Tk, but the issue I was retagging was something that is absolutely not an issue to do with Tkinter).

The questions I have:

1. **How do we undo this *wrong* thing!?** It greatly pollutes the space of searches and worsens the quality of the site.
2. How do we prevent this sort of random rubbish from cropping up in the future? If it's happened to one tag pair, it's probably happened to others.
3. Why was the discussion here ignored? Who was so high-handed and ignorant as to do this without consultation?

Comment: The question I was retagging was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145182/var-not-visible-to-widget-button but it's far from the only question affected.

Comment: You can see when the synonym was (last?) created by going [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) and typing tk into the filter box.

Comment: Yikes! 48k questions need disentangling...

Comment: There are 16 renames so far. I'll axe the alias, but there's nothing I can do about the renamed questions automatically. It's also probably worth renaming [tk] to something else, because Python programmers regularly use `tk` as an import alias for `tkinter`, so leaving both will cause [tag:tk] to be used when [tkinter] should be used instead (because most people don't read tag wikis). I don't have any suggestions for a better name atm though.

Comment: The point on [tag:tk] being abused is also shockingly clear now that the alias has been axed. The amount of Python questions on the first page far outnumbers the questions using C/C++/other languages with direct C interop. This is also not an alias artefact

Comment: Perhaps simply [[tag:tk-toolkit]], @ZoestandswithUkraine , as both the wiki and excerpt refer to it as "The Tk Toolkit".

Comment: @Larnu Sounds reasonable to me. I'll make it so in a few hours if there aren't any objections (or better ideas) in the meanwhile.

Comment: I was going to suggest [tag:tcl-tk], but it seems that the intent is to use the tag for the Tk toolkit itself, agnostic of any particular language binding. So I agree [tag:tk-toolkit] is really the only thing that makes sense.